# Texmaker not updating the PDF viewer

Tags: macos, bash, pdf, pdfviewer, texmaker

I created bash file which constantly compiles the my latex file, the problem is though that the PDFviewer in texmaker doesn't update, eventhoug the raw PDF file is updated. How come is does the PDFviewer keep showing the old PDF until i use Texmaker to compile the texmaker?... I want the embedded PDFviewer in texmaker to update, the PDF it shows even though i don't use texmaker to compile the .tex file.

The bash file.

```
#!/bin/bash
while true
do
    pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode /Users/Johnathan/Documents/Bachelor/Rp/bachelor.tex
    sleep 4
done
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is old, but I just had the same problem and found a solution for some Mac Users at least:

The short explanation: since El Capitan, there is no /usr/ directory anymore, but this is where Texmaker looks for latex. 
In Texmaker -> Preferences -> Commands, substitute every /usr/ expression with /Library/TeX/, which is where Latex is installed.

This document holds all the details. 
https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is not about your script(It works for me), I think is about your PDF viewer.

1)Try using Evince as a PDF reader, it will update your pdf automatically.
It has versions for Windows and Linux, and it is free.

https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Evince/Downloads

2)Another way is using your web browser (I have used Mozilla) as a PDF reader, writing in the URL bar:

file:///Users/Johnathan/Documents/Bachelor/Rp/bachelor.pdf

but this second way has the problem that you must refresh your web browser by yourself.

I hope that helps you!

Comment: My usual PDFviewer which OSx has as standard see it perfectly, and updates when changes instantly as changes occurs.. But the problem is the onboard PDFVIEWER within texmaker.

Comment: Why not change the built-in viewer for your OSX viewer? You can open texmaker and then press Options->Texmaker Configuration and finally change Built-in viewer for your desired viewer.

Comment: That works.. I just want to use the embedded such that i don't need to open a separate window to show the changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem of the PDF viewer not updating.  The fix was:

Select: texmaker, preferences, commands, PDF viewer
Select:  external viewer

Then pick adobe reader or whatever app you use to view pdf files with.

Then you bypass the pdf viewer in textmaker altogether.

Maks

Comment: I have Texworks 0.6.4 for Windows, and I do not see that option. Would you mind giving more details on the sequence to get there?

Comment: Go to `Options` and choose `Configure TexMaker`.

Answer (score -2):

Visit https://i.stack.imgur.com/np55x.png!

[image]

Make sure you choose the `Quick Build` and `View PDF` in the toolbar.